# Proving $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\left({1\over 4x^2}\right)\ln x\cdot{\mathrm dx\over x^2}=-\sqrt{\pi\over 2}\cdot\left({\pi-2\gamma \over 4}\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Consider these two similar integrals

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\left({1\over 4x^2}\right)\ln x\cdot{\mathrm dx\over x^2}=-\sqrt{\pi\over 2}\cdot\left({\pi-2\gamma \over 4}\right)\tag1$$
>
> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\left({1\over 4x^2}\right)\ln^2x\cdot{\mathrm dx\over x^2}=\sqrt{\pi\over 2}\cdot\left({\pi-2\gamma \over 4}\right)^2\tag2$$

How does one prove $(1)$ and $(2)$?

**An attempt:**

Using the $\sin x$ series, and let $u=\ln x$, then $(1)$ becomes

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\over 2^{2n+1}(2n+1)!}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}ue^{-2(n+1)u}\mathrm du\tag3$$

Integral $(3)$ diverges.

**Another attempt:**

$u={1\over 4x^2}$ then $(1)$ becomes

$$-{1\over 8}\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin u\ln{(4u)}\cdot{\mathrm du\over u^{3/2}}\tag4$$

Using $\ln u$ series, then $(4)$ becomes

$$-{1\over 4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{1\over 2n+1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left({4u-1\over 4u+1}\right)^{2n+1}\cdot{\sin u\over u^{3/2}}\mathrm du\tag5$$

Using $\coth^{-1} x={1\over 2}\ln{x-1\over x+1}$

$$-{1\over 4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{1\over 2n+1}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{2(2n+1)\coth^{-1}4x}\cdot{\sin u\over u^{3/2}}\mathrm du\tag6$$

How else can we proceed?

Comment: I think you may want to be careful. The series definining $\sin$ is _not_ uniformly convergent on unbounded intervals, so you may not be allowed to integrate it term by term.

Comment: Perhaps the keyhole contour of $\sin(1/4x^2)\ln^2(x)\frac1{x^2}$?

Comment: Note that you took the series expansion of $\ln(u)$, which doesn't converge over $(0,+\infty)$...

Comment: what is your feeling about this integral? after around 200 questions on this topic, you should have a pretty reliable one...

Comment: After this 200 questions I will take a course in Calculus and to see what the hell did I posted so far. Thank you for reminding me @tired.

Comment: @Bui your questions are pretty fine, i'm just curious how your intuition develops

Comment: This so-called intuition begin when I was 16 years, so one day I found this site accidentally, so I got a base to release all these equations and formulas off my mind. It is very stressful keeping these ideas in one mind. Maths is like a class-A drug, so addictive.

Comment: I see you once a while answering my post, but you need to ask Professor @Jack D'Aurizio how does he develops such an intuition of knowledge to answer every questions. Maybe he has magic fingers.

Comment: @Bui years of experience sir Jack has ahead of us :-P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recall
$$ \int_0^\infty u^te^{-su}du=\frac{\Gamma(t+1)}{s^{t+1}}. $$
So
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{t}\sin u\mathrm du\\
&=&\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\Im \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}u^{t} e^{iu}\mathrm du=\Im \frac{\Gamma(t+1)}{(-i)^{t+1}}\\
&=&\Im \Gamma(t+1)(i)^{t+1}=\Gamma(t+1)\sin(\frac{(t+1)\pi}{2}).
\end{eqnarray}
Let
$$ I(a)=\int_0^{\infty}x^{-a}\sin(\frac1{4x^2})dx $$
and then
$$I(a)=-2^{-2+a}\int_0^{\infty}u^{\frac{-3+a}2}\sin udu=-2^{a-2}\sin(\frac{(a-1)\pi}{4})\Gamma(\frac{a-1}{2}). $$
So
\begin{eqnarray}
I'(2)&=&-2^{a-2}\ln2\sin(\frac{(a-1)\pi}{4})\Gamma(\frac{a-1}{2})-2^{a-4}\pi\cos(\frac{(a-1)\pi}{4})\Gamma(\frac{a-1}{2})\\
&&-2^{a-3}\sin(\frac{(a-1)\pi}{4})\Gamma'(\frac{a-1}{2})\bigg|_{a=2}\\
&=&-\ln2\cdot\frac1{\sqrt2}\sqrt{\pi}-\frac\pi 4\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sqrt\pi-\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\Gamma'(\frac12)
\end{eqnarray}
Noting
$$ \frac{\Gamma'(z+1)}{\Gamma(z+1)}=-\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{z+n}\right)$$
one has
$$ \Gamma'(\frac12)=\Gamma(\frac12)\left[-\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n-\frac12}\right)\right]=\sqrt{\pi}(-\gamma-2\ln2).$$
Thus
$$ I'(2)=-\sqrt{\pi\over 2}\left({\pi-2\gamma \over 4}\right). $$
You can treat $I''(2)$ in the same way and the calculation will be longer.