# How can we prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln (x)\sin\left[\pi\left(x^2-{1\over 4}\right)\right]\mathrm dx={\pi\over 8}?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Consider this integral

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln (x)\sin\left[\pi\left(x^2-{1\over 4}\right)\right]\mathrm dx={\pi\over 8}\tag1$$

How can we prove $(1)?$

**An attempt:**

Very difficult to even make an attempt of just varying $(1)$

Rewrite $(1)$ as

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(x)[\sin(\pi x^2)-\cos(\pi x^2)]\mathrm dx\tag2$$

Comment: You asked before. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2199752/proving-int-0-infty-sin-left1-over-4x2-right-ln-x-cdot-mathrm-dx-ov?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**. By using the [Euler gamma evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Definition),
$$
\int_0^\infty x^s\cdot e^{-(a+i\pi)x^2}dx=\frac12 \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)}{(a+i\pi)^{ s/2+1/2}},\quad \text{Re}(s)>-1,\,a>0,\tag1
$$ one gets, as $a \to 0^+$,
$$
\int_0^{\infty} x^s\cos\left(\pi x^2\right)\,dx=\frac{\pi^{-s/2-1/2}}{2} \cos \left(\frac{\pi(s+1)}{4} \right)\cdot\Gamma \left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right),\quad-1<\Re(s)<1, \tag2
$$$$
\int_0^{\infty} x^s\sin\left(\pi x^2\right)\,dx=\frac{\pi^{-s/2-1/2}}{2} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  (s+1)}{4} \right)\cdot\Gamma \left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right),\quad-1<\Re(s)<1, \tag3
$$ then differentiating $(2)$ and $(3)$ with respect to $s$ and making $s=0$ gives

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\ln (x)\cos\left[\pi\left(x^2-{1\over 4}\right)\right]\mathrm dx&=-\frac{1}{4} (\gamma +\log (4 \pi )),\tag4
> \\\\
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\ln (x)\sin\left[\pi\left(x^2-{1\over 4}\right)\right]\mathrm dx&={\pi\over 8}.\tag5
> \end{align}
> $$

where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: Very elegant method.

Comment: @MrYouMath Thank you.